# Explanation of declaration - (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender; iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, declaration, ibaction

everywhere they say what IBAction is but do not explain what the whole declaration means.

What is sender and id?

Regards,
Namratha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. According to my knowledge `IBAction` just implies `void`
2. `id` is a generic C type, which accepts objects of any kind/class. It is some what similar to **void pointer** in `C`. We can use `id` as a parameter of a method, in case, if objects of difference kind of classes will access that method.
3. `sender`, here,

   - is a human-named parameter name (you can name it anything)
   - it refers the object which calls the method `changeGreeting:`

**An Example:**

Lets assume the method `changeGreeting:` is defined in `ClassA`, and it reads like the following.

```
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

    [sender setText:@"Hello %@", [sender class]];

    // Nothing can be returned from this method
}
```

And consider we have the following lines in `Class B`.

```
// LINE 1
[aLabel addTarget:objOfClassA action:@selector(changeGreeting:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// LINE 2
[aTextField addTarget:objOfClassA action:@selector(changeGreeting:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In LINE 1, `aLabel` is the **sender** and `objOfClassA` is the **receiver**. And in LINE 2: `aTextField` is the **sender** and `objOfClassA` is the **receiver**. Here`aLabel` & `aTextField` are called **senders** because they are **calling** the method `changeGreeting:`. And `objOfClassA` is called **receiver** because `objOfClassA's` `changeGreeting:` method is **called** here.

When the user touches inside the `aLabel` or `aTextField`, their `text` will be changed to `Hello UILabel` or `Hello UITextField` respectively.

**The other Way:**
 We can also call `changeGreeting:` method of `objOfClassA` from `Class B` like the following.

```
[objOfClassA changeGreeting:aLabel];
[objOfClassA changeGreeting:aTextField];
```

As the above code is self explanatory, `objOfClassA` is the **receiver**. But `aLabel` & `aTextField` are not the **senders**. Because they are not invoking the method. Here they are just the arguments. Here the actual sender is `Class B`, but `aLabel` and `aTextField` are passed in the argument `(id)sender`.  Either way the result of the method execution is same.

Comment: Not quite. `UILabel` and `UITextField` are not calling the method, they’re _receiving a message_. Also, your example would be correct had you written `[aLabel changeGreeting:self]`. Cocoa Touch does fill the `sender` parameter with whichever object is sending the action. If you’re doing it programatically, you should pass the `sender` parameter as well, and `self` is usually a good argument.

Comment: Thank you Simon and Bavarious.                                     If Cocoa Touch does fill the sender parameter, then why is self required?Also, please explain 'receiving a message'

Comment: @Namratha: I am really sorry. I was wrong in my answer. I have edited my answer now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Namratha When I say that Cocoa Touch fills the sender parameter, I mean that the classes in the framework (e.g. UIButton, UITextField) will place an propriate object as the sender argument. When you are sending an IB action, you are responsible for passing an argument in the same way as the classes in the framework do.

Comment: @Namratha Objective-c is a message-based language: a function or method sends a message to a certain object. This is similar to calling a method on said object. This object receives a message, i.e., a method is called upon it. You can read more about Objective-C messaging at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should check out a Objective-C tutorial ([such as this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)), as this is pretty basic.

The IBAction is defined as "void", so it means that the method does not have a return value. It is useful only for Interface Builder, so it knows which of your methods are actually action you can link.

The (id)sender part is a (the only) parameter to your method, which is named sender. (id) says that the type of the parameter can be any object:

From [Objective-C FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/computer-lang/Objective-C/faq/):

> What is id?
>   It's a generic C type that Objective-C uses for an arbitrary object. [...]

Answer (score 1):

`IBAction` is a keyword (`#define`'d to `void`) that Interface Builder looks for in your source code, and if it finds it as a return type, it will add it to the list of possibile actions you can wire up your IB elements to.

`id` is a generic object type in Objective-C that denotes *any* Objective-C object.

and `sender` is just the name of the `id`-typed parameter.

Comment: IBAction is not a typedef to void, but actually a macro defined as void. You won't be able to create a variable such as "IBAction * something;" (which of course wouldn't make any sense anyway).

Comment: Agree with x3ro. `IBAction` is a macro. It is not keyword, nor typedef. I know it's not so important practically, but better make it accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally saying: IBAction is a keyword to identify methods you could link to through Interface Builder. (id)Sender is necessary to identify the object is triggering the method in case you use the same method for several controls.